# How do I approach finding the radius with the measurements given?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

A parallelogram with three congruent inscribed circles is painted across a 20-foot by 12-foot rectangular banner as shown. The longer sides of the parallelogram have length 15 feet. What is the radius of each circle? Express your answer as a common fraction.

[image: shortened_banner]

I thought the three diameters of the circle added together would result in the 12-foot height of the circle, meaning the radius of each circle is 2, but I think there is more to it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Hint: Let $A$ and $C$ be centers of bottom and middle circles. Construct $\triangle ABC$ which $AB$ horizontal and $BC$ vertical. What is the ratio $\frac{BC}{AC}$?

Comment: Hi @ achille hui  I propose that we help him with an easier question ; ( not suitable for this site etc. ) to close vote it to me appears bit on the harsher side

Comment: @Narasimham the dimension of the 2nd picture is incorrect, if the two slant lines passes through the vertices, the width of the rectangle should be $\frac{192}{13}$ instead of $20$.

Comment: Right my bad; missed erasing 20 in my previous edit , now put it in; however shall roll back , if you suggest..( to provide an easier alternative for OP.)